# How to fix an error "CODE NOT FOUND" in Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I tried to deploy my app to Vercel (create-react-app starter). It was deploy successful, no errors in console or my vercel account. But when i clicked a link, i have this message:

> 404: NOT_FOUND
> Code: NOT_FOUND
> ID: ...

How to fix that? I have React (hooks, router) and Redux store, no database, no next.js.
Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. Turns out I had the wrong framework preset set in Vercel. Check your Build & Development Settings for your project. Be sure that 'create-react-app' is selected.

Comment: Thanks @Drowned ✅ ✅ ✅

Comment: That didn't work for me.(in vite app)
In my case Clicking any link (like to "/dev") was working and even the url changes in the browser 
but if I write the  url by myself and try to get the page it sends a 404.

Comment: @CircuitPlanet had the same problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644138/7731997) pointed me to the [`rewrites`](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/rewrites) section for the `vercel.json` file. Adding this to the vercel config file worked for me: `{ "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }] }`

Answer (score 21):

i fixed this issue just now. turns out that only 1 route works, the "/" home route and other routes work for a short time, when you refresh the page, it shows a 404 page. it only happens if you don't configure your `vercel.json`. The routes don't get recognized except the "/" Home page route.

follow these steps:

1. go to your project and add a `vercel.json` file. Then add these lines

```
{ "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }] }
```

2. On the vercel deployment dashboard, pick vitejs as framework
3. to learn more about this, head to their [official documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/project-configuration)

I really hope it helps anyone on the internet

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the build & deployment settings & check that you have selected framework if it doesn't work then add your custom commands.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My app was located in a subdirectory. So I had to set the **Root Directory** correctly in the project settings in order to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

for node js

```
   {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the framework as NextJs. that was the case for me. After it re-deploy the build.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but for a next.js app. For some reason it was set to default other, I changed it to next.js for framework and it worked. Note that this would depend on what your base code is in. So choose the framework appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

For the the people who can not find Project Settings like myself, Vercel UI maybe a bit tricky to get used to.

There are 2 different settings - Vercel overall setting and your individial project setting. The page you need to change Build & Development Settings or root directory, build commands is NOT the Setting link on the top menu:
[image: Vercel top menu]

Instead it is the one when you click three dots on the right side of your project name in your project tile.

To go there click on the 'yourAccount's projects' on the left top corner, near black trinagle and blueish circle. It will open list of your projects in tiles.

Now click on three dots near the project you want to change and you will see on the context menu:

'Add Favorite', 'View Logs', 'Manage Domains', 'Transfer Project', 'Settings'. The last one is what you need:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

similar thing i had faced in vite js framework

step-1 - add **vercel.json** in your root path of your project
step-2 - add the below code in there -

```
{ "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }] }
```

step-3 - make sure vercel deployment dashboard, pick your required **framework**

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by removing this line `"baseUrl": "."` in the jsconfig.json/tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Biggest troll, after removing "baseUrl": "." my auth stopped working