# Vercel error ( Rollup failed to resolve import "react-router-dom" )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite, vercel

Currently I'm trying to deploy by app using Vercel. I'm using React (with Vite), NodeJS and MongoDB. I receive the following error: [vercel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUmci.png).

This is my vercel.json:

```
{
    "buildCommand": "cd client && npm install && ./node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js build",
    "outputDirectory": "client/dist",
    "framework": "vite",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/server/(.*)",
        "destination": "/server/index.js"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My file structure: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBNmh.png)

main.jsx where the error occurs:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserContextProvider } from './context/UserContext'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <UserContextProvider>
            <App />
        </UserContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>

)
```

The buildCommand works in the terminal and creates the 'dist' folder (which I delete), but not with Vercel. I've tried solutions from this post, however they have not worked as of yet.
[Why does react-router not works at vercel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815012/why-does-react-router-not-works-at-vercel)

Help would be great, thanks.